# Localization in log4j

Tags: java, localization, log4j

I am trying to localize the messages in a java application. I am using ResourceBundle loading based on Locale.

I want the messages on console to be localized and messages in log files to be in English.

What I am doing is this:

```
 if (bundle != null) { 
     MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat(bundle.getString(message));
     Object [] messageArgument = new Object[] {"arg1"};
     logger.info(formatter.format(messageArgument)); 
  }
```

I have set the ConsoleHandler threshold to INFO.
The issue is, now even the info log file will contain localized message along with the console.

Is there a way to put English messages to log file and localized messages to console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: complete rewrite**

Normally when logging a string is passed to the logger which is already localized and cannot be translated after this. However the type for the message in log4j is actual Object and only later within the framework it is converted to an actual string. This is done by log4j before the message is passed on to the appenders but it looks like the appender can still get at the original object. So it would seem to be possible to write custom appenders for log4j in combination with a custom message type that would give the behaviour you want but it will be complex.

I think you will be better of putting a layer on top of the console and log4j and just let that handle sending a localized message to the console directly and sending an english message to log4j.

Comment: But I need to set INFO threshold for ConsoleAppender. 
So when I do logger.info() or logger.error(), it goes both into log file and comes on the console.

If I load English bundle, console messages won't be localized.

Comment: @Chandramouli: you will need to use two Bundles. One initialized for English the other for whatever language you need

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 
If I have understood correctly, you are suggesting I have to log like this:
    log.info(englishMessage);
    log.info(localMessage);

Even this will not solve the problem right?

Comment: @Chandramoul: Sorry misunderstood your initial question.

Comment: @Eelke

Thanks!!
This is what I did:
1. Define a custom log level which is higher than error.
2. Set console appender to the custom log level
3. Logger class which internally uses log4j and expose methods error,info,debug. 
4. These methods accept message id and message parameters.
5. Inside these methods, log using English bundle into the files and local bundle to console.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only doing this logging in one place (or a few) you could write the logging to two logger instances:

```
if (bundle != null) {
  MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat(bundle.getString(message));
  Object [] messageArgument = new Object[] {"arg1"};
  locale_logger.info(formatter.format(messageArgument)); 
  english_logger.info(message);
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to initialize loggers in such case?
Currently this is what I am doing:

`PropertyConfigurator.configure(configFile);`
`logger = Logger.getLogger(className);`

And the configFile is:

'log4j.rootLogger= STDOUT,  INFOLOG

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
..
..
log4j.appender.STDOUT.threshold=INFO

..
log4j.appender.INFOLOG.threshold=INFO
..'

Comment: You don't have to use class name or class when you create the logger, you can use any string.  english_logger  = Logger.getLogger("English"); then configure log4j to only write these messages to the file appended